# Skype for Business Client (Endpoint) App using UCMA 6.0 SDK does not record call when ported. "Recorder cannot start due to I/O Error."

Tags: skype-for-business, ucma

Built a Skype for Business Client (Endpoint) App using the UCMA 6.0 SDK. It is a C# console app or placng test calls. Application runs as designed on Windows 10 Dell laptop where it was developed using Visual Studio 2017.

When ported to a 2nd Windows 10 Dell laptop, the calls complete but the recording feature from Class RTC.Collaboration.AudioVideo.Recorder gives an error message:**"Recorder cannot start due to I/O Error."**

Snopper analysis of the OCS log: TL_ERROR, TF_Component, SinkRecorderImpl.StartRecord.Imp.

Even tried building the app on the target laptop. Same issue.  **Any ideas on why the I/O error?**

Answer (score 0):

You must create the log folder on the target computer.  I had created the parent folder but not the specific subfolder for recordings. Manually creating the subfolder solved the problem.